# How to replace character in the index column of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code piece:

```
d = {'col1': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'col2': ["AAAD", "BBC", "KLMA", "ABC"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2
0   0       AAAD
1   1       BBC
2   2       KLMA
3   3       ABC
```

And I set the index to "col2". And after that, if I need to change any occurace of "." with a "-" in the index column (if there is any). Here is what I do:

```
df.index = df['col2']
df.index = df.index.str.replace('.','-', regex=True)
df
```

Output:

```
        col1    col2
col2        
AAAD    0       AAAD
BBC     1       BBC
KLMA    2       KLMA
ABC     3       ABC
```

Since there is no "." in the index column, nothing is changed.

This was just an example I produced. I have the same code in a production environment and it produces the following dataframe at the end:

```
        col1    col2
col2        
----    0       AAAD
---     1       BBC
----    2       KLMA
---     3       ABC
```

I just cannot understand why. Is it related to the Python version? In the production environment, which I am not able to share here due to its complexity, it replaces all characters with "-". Why am I having this problem?

Comment: This is much depend on Pandas version as well. But if you don't want to use regex, in which `.` is a special character, then just pass `regex=True`, and `.str.replace` will treat `.` as a normal character.

Comment: @QuangHoang I already set regex=True. But I still have the problem. Am I misinterpreting your comment?

Comment: oh, I meant `regex=False`.

Comment: Do you mean .str.replace will treat "." as a normal character if I set regex=False?

Comment: Yes, it treats `.`. as a normal character if `regex=False`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Setting regex to False really solved the problem. I also recognized that this problem started happening with the latest version of Pandas. The production environment is using the latest Pandas version and I had an older version locally on my computer. After updating pandas locally I could reproduce the problem and setting regex to False solved it. I am still confused though what the difference is between setting regex to False and True.

Comment: That's the gist of it `regex=True` treats the first argument as a regex pattern. In this case, `.` is a regex pattern which represents any chracters. More info in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A period '.' is considered a special regex character.  To match a character having special meaning in regex, you need to use a escape sequence prefix with a backslash `\.`

Otherwise, if you use . (dot) standalone and without a backslash, as you have in your example, the period is going to match any character (except for next line) and then replace it with a - (dash)

The only change is adding a backslash before the period:

`df.index = df.index.str.replace('\.','-', regex=True)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the difference between putting "\" before the "." and setting regex to False instead?

Comment: There's no difference in the outcome.  If you set regex to True, it will treat a handful of characters as having a special meaning - your period is no longer a period in Regex and you'll need a backslash before your period to tell the system to treat it like an actual period vs. a speicalized regex character. If you set regex to False, characters such as a period no longer take on a special meaning, bc this special meaning is tied to regex only, when regex is set to False, you period is just another period ;)

Comment: Your formula either needs to be df.index = df.index.str.replace('.','-', regex=False) OR df.index = df.index.str.replace('\.','-', regex=True)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and giving such a detailed explanation. Legend!